# Create a socket in Swift

Tags: xcode, sockets, swift, socketserver

I'm trying to write a simple echo server with swift. The examples I found are either [non-functional and low-level](https://gist.github.com/satoshiam/65f74106f5c69697314f) or [written in objective-c](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaEcho/Introduction/Intro.html).

I failed at a lot of things, I will start from the top. I cannot manage to create a simple socket using higher-level functions like `CFSocketCreate`. This is what I ended up with:

```
class EchoServer : NSObject, NSStreamDelegate
{
    private var serverSocket: CFSocketRef?

    func start()
    {
        self.serverSocket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, 2, &self.acceptConnection, NSNull())
    }

    func acceptConnection(socket: CFSocketRef, type: CFSocketCallBackType, address: CFDataRef, data: UnsafePointer<Void>, info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
    {
        // Accept connection and stuff later
    }
}
```

I am new to xcode/objectivec/swift and I'm having a hard time even understanding the error message. The above code leaves me simply with

> EchoServer.swift:31:93: '(CFSocketRef, type: CFSocketCallBackType, address: CFDataRef, data: UnsafePointer, info: UnsafeMutablePointer) -> ()' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T10'

I'm not even able to make head or tail of this.

Comment: any luck with creating your custom server in Swift? I am working on it too, and stuck on the  first line in EchoServer :)

Comment: Sorry no. Swift kept being so unbearably buggy that I entirely switched to nw.js for my project.

Answer (score 5):

If somebody is still looking for the answer on this question. I modified code a little. There were some typing issues in the callback, plus it could not be a function on the class.

```
import CoreFoundation

func acceptConnection(socket: CFSocket!, type: CFSocketCallBackType, address: CFData!, data: UnsafePointer<Void>, info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
{
    // Accept connection and stuff later
}

class EchoServer : NSObject, NSStreamDelegate
{
    private var serverSocket: CFSocketRef?

    func start()
    {
        self.serverSocket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, 2, acceptConnection, nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You might take a look at `GCDAsyncSocket` as it handles a lot of the "plumbing" for you.

I was building a simple server in Swift as a learning exercise. There might be some things in there you could use. Here is the class that deals with creating the socket:
[Github Link](https://github.com/picciano/SwiftServe/blob/master/SwiftServe/SwiftServe/Server.swift)

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: @zoyt to be honest, the op doesn't even ask a question, but thanks for the criticism